# Проверка наличия записей в таблице

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите как или каким запросом к БД можно проверить отсутствие в таблице 3400 записей?
Есть idшники этих записей они уникальные и не имеют связи между собой.

Comment: а отсутствие одной уже умеете проверять? а двух? а трёх?

Comment: допуская, что топик-автор не владеет sql, намекнём select id from table where id in (список id через запятую)

Comment: а результат какой должен быть? Вот есть 3400 айдишников, из них 1200 есть, а 2200 - нет, то какой результат ожидается?

Answer (score -1):

Есть два варианта:

1. При помощи скрипта на каком-то языке программирования перебирать каждый id и проверять есть ли он в БД:

   select count(id) as cnt from table where id=id
2. Собрать все id в один запрос вида:

   select id from table where id in(id,id,id,id)

Comment: Как второй вариант **проверяет наличие/отсутствие**?

Comment: Так запрос выведет все имеющиеся в базе id. Соответственно тех которых нет - не выведет

Comment: Выведет/не выведет !== **проверяет**

Comment: И как вы думаете, что будет с вашим запросом при 3000 идентификаторов?

Comment: Именно поэтому и был предложен он как второй вариант, если нет рук написать первый. Ну кстати и по второму варианту тоже будет думать долго, но запрос выполнится без проблем. Зря минусуете.

Comment: Ну да, на своей тестовой базе прогнал запрос "эмулятор" : select id from ls where id in (select id from ls limit 5000), отработал за 3 секунды. Проблемы нет